# How to make a PHP script that's pluginable?

Tags: php

I'm creating my own script using the CodeIgniter MVC framework. Now, i want users to easily modify the site functionality and adding their own without modifying the code which i've already written.

How do i make my site pluginable ?

EDIT: The users would be the site admins. Not the end user. Basically just like drupal or joomla. Want the admin to be able to create/add plugins to extend site functionality.

Comment: When you say you want your site to be able to utilize plugins, what sorts of things are you envisioning those plugins doing? If I wanted to write a plugin for your site that created a new page that allowed anyone to view / alter the values in any table in the site's database, would that be a valid plugin? If not, why not; what are your limits?

Comment: No limits. The plugin would be able to retrieve/delete any data from the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be a better way that's specific to CodeIgniter, but this is what I would do:

First, create functions for various "hook points" in your code. Say, a function named `PreArticle` that you call in your code, before an article is displayed.

Allow the user to write code like this:

```
    addHook_PreArticle('funcToCall');

    function funcToCall( &$articleText ) {
       $articleText = str_replace('Hello', 'World', $articleText);
    }
```

`addHook_PreArticle` is a function you've defined, which would add the passed string to some internal list. Then when the `PreArticle` function is called, each of those functions are executed, passing in any appropriate parameters that you define.

Answer (score 0):

Many CMS's Like Joomla and Blogs like Wordpress use variable function names:

```
$function="phpinfo";
$function();
```

You could load this into an array to create a list of functions that can be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

That's a perfect case to use the Observer Pattern.
http://devzone.zend.com/article/5